# jQuery to make dynamically created radiobutton groups mutually exclusive

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I have some C# (asp.net mvc 3) code that is generating radio buttons on the page and assigning them to groups dynamically.  I have some jQuery that will make "all" radio buttons on the page mutually exclusive but that isn't exactly what the requirement is supposed to do.

Each group needs to be mutually exclusive and the code I am using now makes every radio button the page mutually exclusive and that will not work.

How can I make each group mutually exclusive?  This has to be dynamic as the group name is dynamically generated at run time.

Rendered Html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<!-- paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/ -->
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="no-js lt-ie9" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
    <html class="no-js" lang="en">
<!--<![endif]-->
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<!-- Set the viewport width to device width for mobile -->
<meta name="viewport" content = "initial-scale=1,user-scalable=no,maximum-scale=1">

<head>
    <title>Approvals Edit</title>


        <link href="/camms/Content/themes/camms/jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.css?build=1.0.4778.19080" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

        <link href="/camms/Content/themes/camms/tinyeditor.css?build=1.0.4778.19080" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <link href="/camms/Content/themes/zurb/globals.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="/camms/Content/themes/zurb/forms.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="/camms/Content/themes/zurb/grid.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="/camms/Content/themes/zurb/mobile.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="/camms/Content/themes/zurb/typography.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="/camms/Content/themes/zurb/app.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />


        <script src="/camms/Scripts/jquery-1.6.2.min.js?build=1.0.4778.19080" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script src="/camms/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.16.min.js?build=1.0.4778.19080" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script src="/camms/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js?build=1.0.4778.19080" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script src="/camms/Scripts/jquery.blockUI.js?build=1.0.4778.19080" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script src="/camms/Scripts/jquery.scrollTo-1.4.2-min.js?build=1.0.4778.19080" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script src="/camms/Scripts/jquery.maskedinput-1.3.js?build=1.0.4778.19080" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script src="/camms/Scripts/tinyeditor_packed.js?build=1.0.4778.19080" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script src="/camms/Scripts/PrintArea.js?build=1.0.4778.19080" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script src="/camms/Scripts/jquery.base64.min.js?build=1.0.4778.19080" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script src="/camms/Scripts/jquery.pagination.js?build=1.0.4778.19080" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script src="/camms/Scripts/jquery.sorting.js?build=1.0.4778.19080" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script src="/camms/Scripts/jquery.filtering.js?build=1.0.4778.19080" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script src="/camms/Scripts/jquery.validate.js?build=1.0.4778.19080" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script src="/camms/Scripts/CammsTemplate.js?build=1.0.4778.19080" type="text/javascript"></script>


        <script src="/camms/Scripts/jquery.stretcher.js?build=1.0.4778.19080" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script src="/camms/Scripts/jquery.mobile-menu.js?build=1.0.4778.19080" type="text/javascript"></script>


    <link href="/camms/Content/themes/zurb/ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>


    <div style="position:absolute; botton:0; left:0; background-color:black; color:white">
        Development
    </div>   

        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $(':input:enabled:visible:first').focus();
        });

        //rootPath is used to construct URLs in attached javascript files
        rootPath = "/camms/";
    </script>


    <script src="/camms/Scripts/SessionMonitor.js?build=1.0.4778.19080" type="text/javascript"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        var rootPath = '/camms/';
        var sessionMonitor = new SessionMonitor({
            extendSessionButton:    $('#keepWorkingBtn'),
            extendSessionUrl:       rootPath + "JSON/KeepSessionAlive",
            extendSessionMessage:   $('#extendSession'),
            sessionExpiredOkButton: $('#sessionExpiredBtn'),
            expiredSessionMessage:  $('#sessionTimedOut'),
            expiredSessionUrl:      rootPath,
            sessionTimeout :        1800
        });
    });
</script>

<div id="sessionTimedOut" style="display: none; padding:10px;">
    <p>Your session has expired</p>
    <input type="button" id="sessionExpiredBtn" class="small blue radius button" value="Ok"/>
</div>

<div id="extendSession" style="display: none; padding:10px;">
    <p>Your session will expire in <span id="sessionTimeRemaining"></span> seconds</p>
    <input type="button" id="keepWorkingBtn" class="small blue radius button" value="Keep Working"/>
</div>    

    <div class="container">
        <div id="header" class="row">
            <div id="mobile-logo" class="show-on-phones clearfix" >
                <h2>
                    <a href="/camms/">CAMMS</a>
                </h2>
            </div>

            <a href="/camms/" class="hide-on-phones">    <img src="/camms/Content/themes/camms/Images/logo.png" class="logo" alt="" />
</a>
            <div id="user-info-panel">

                <span class="hide-on-phones">
                    Wednesday, January 30, 2013<br />
                </span>

                Baker, Nathan |

                <!-- Show the current office -->
Computer Services,  Central<br />

                <!-- show the change office link -->
            </div>
        </div>


        <label id="mobile-category-name" class="show-on-phones">
            Category: Certifications
        </label>
        <div id="menuBar" class="row">
            <div id="breadcrumb" class="hide-on-phones">
                Category: Certifications
            </div>




<ul class="hide-on-phones">
        <li class='item  '>
                     <span class="disabled">Enrollment</span>

        </li>
        <li class='item selected radius '>
                     <span class="disabled">Approvals</span>

        </li>
        <li class='item  '>
                     <span class="disabled">Maintenance</span>

        </li>
        <li class='item  '>
                     <span class="disabled">Scheduling</span>

        </li>
</ul>

<label class="mobile-nav-level1 show-on-phones">
    Process:  &nbsp;
</label>
<select class="show-on-phones mobile-nav" style="margin-top:8px;">
            <option  value="/camms/Certifications/Scheduling" >
                Scheduling
            </option>
            <option  value="/camms/Certifications/Maintenance" >
                Maintenance
            </option>
            <option selected value="/camms/Certifications/Approvals" >
                Approvals
            </option>
            <option  value="/camms/Certifications/Enrollment" >
                Enrollment
            </option>
</select>

           </div>
        <div id="moreMenu">

<div class="moreMenuContainer radius" >
    <ul>
    </ul>
</div>
<span style="clear:right"></span>        </div>

        <div id="page-content" class="row radius-bottom">
            <div id="leftColumn" class="five columns">


<div style="overflow:hidden" class="hide-on-phones">
    <ul>
    </ul>
</div> 

<label class="mobile-nav-level2 show-on-phones">
    Sub-Process:  &nbsp;
</label>

<select class="show-on-phones mobile-nav " >
</select>
               </div>

            <div id="rightColumn" class="fifteen columns">
                <div id="title-bar" class="row">
                    <div id="titleBarOptions"></div>
                    <h2>Approvals Edit</h2>


                    <hr/>
                </div>

                <div id="scrollable-area" >


<form action="/camms/CertificationApproval/Edit/Certifications/Approvals/10556" method="post">    <span>

        <div class="row line editcolumn">
                <div class="three columns ">

                        <label for="PersonName" class="hide-on-phones" style="white-space: nowrap">Attendee</label>
                        <span class="clearfix hide-on-phones"></span>
                        <label for="PersonName" class="show-on-phones">Attendee &nbsp; </label>
                        <span class="clearfix show-on-phones"></span>                        


<input disabled="disabled" id="PersonName" name="PersonName" type="text" value="Brandhuber, Scott J." />
<input id="PersonName" name="PersonName" type="hidden" value="Brandhuber, Scott J." />


                </div>
                <div class="four columns ">

                        <label for="Certification" class="hide-on-phones" style="white-space: nowrap">Certification</label>
                        <span class="clearfix hide-on-phones"></span>
                        <label for="Certification" class="show-on-phones">Certification &nbsp; </label>
                        <span class="clearfix show-on-phones"></span>                        


<input disabled="disabled" id="Certification" name="Certification" type="text" value="ALDOT Concrete Technician" />
<input id="Certification" name="Certification" type="hidden" value="ALDOT Concrete Technician" />


                </div>
                <div class="one columns ">

                        <label for="Score" class="hide-on-phones" style="white-space: nowrap">Score</label>
                        <span class="clearfix hide-on-phones"></span>
                        <label for="Score" class="show-on-phones">Score &nbsp; </label>
                        <span class="clearfix show-on-phones"></span>                        


<input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Score must be a number." data-val-required="The Score field is required." disabled="disabled" id="Score" name="Score" type="text" value="85" />
<input id="Score" name="Score" type="hidden" value="85" />


                </div>
                <div class="two columns ">

                        <label for="ExamProficiency" class="hide-on-phones" style="white-space: nowrap">Proficiency</label>
                        <span class="clearfix hide-on-phones"></span>
                        <label for="ExamProficiency" class="show-on-phones">Proficiency &nbsp; </label>
                        <span class="clearfix show-on-phones"></span>                        


<input disabled="disabled" id="ExamProficiency" name="ExamProficiency" type="text" value="" />
<input id="ExamProficiency" name="ExamProficiency" type="hidden" value="" />


                </div>
                <div class="one columns ">

                        <label for="Approve" class="hide-on-phones" style="white-space: nowrap">Approve</label>
                        <span class="clearfix hide-on-phones"></span>
                        <label for="Approve" class="show-on-phones">Approve &nbsp; </label>
                        <span class="clearfix show-on-phones"></span>                        

                    <input GroupName="group_64" falsevalue="N" id="Approve" name="Approve" truevalue="Y" type="radio" value="False" />
                </div>
                <div class="one columns ">

                        <label for="Reject" class="hide-on-phones" style="white-space: nowrap">Reject</label>
                        <span class="clearfix hide-on-phones"></span>
                        <label for="Reject" class="show-on-phones">Reject &nbsp; </label>
                        <span class="clearfix show-on-phones"></span>                        

                    <input GroupName="group_64" falsevalue="Y" id="Reject" name="Reject" truevalue="N" type="radio" value="False" />
                </div>
       </div>
<input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Person Certification Id must be a number." data-val-required="The Person Certification Id field is required." id="PersonCertificationId" name="PersonCertificationId" type="hidden" value="1478" /><input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Ref Wtf Members Id must be a number." data-val-required="The Ref Wtf Members Id field is required." id="RefWtfMembersId" name="RefWtfMembersId" type="hidden" value="10006" /><input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Worker Id must be a number." data-val-required="The Worker Id field is required." id="WorkerId" name="WorkerId" type="hidden" value="10556" /><input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Wtf Approval Id must be a number." data-val-required="The Wtf Approval Id field is required." id="WtfApprovalId" name="WtfApprovalId" type="hidden" value="0" /><input id="MembersId" name="MembersId" type="hidden" value="10011" /><input id="PreviousUrl" name="PreviousUrl" type="hidden" value="" /><input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Last Modified By Id must be a number." id="LastModifiedById" name="LastModifiedById" type="hidden" value="" />           
        <div class="row line editcolumn">
                <div class="three columns ">

                        <label for="PersonName" class="hide-on-phones" style="white-space: nowrap">Attendee</label>
                        <span class="clearfix hide-on-phones"></span>
                        <label for="PersonName" class="show-on-phones">Attendee &nbsp; </label>
                        <span class="clearfix show-on-phones"></span>                        


<input disabled="disabled" id="PersonName" name="PersonName" type="text" value="Duck, Daffy " />
<input id="PersonName" name="PersonName" type="hidden" value="Duck, Daffy " />


                </div>
                <div class="four columns ">

                        <label for="Certification" class="hide-on-phones" style="white-space: nowrap">Certification</label>
                        <span class="clearfix hide-on-phones"></span>
                        <label for="Certification" class="show-on-phones">Certification &nbsp; </label>
                        <span class="clearfix show-on-phones"></span>                        


<input disabled="disabled" id="Certification" name="Certification" type="text" value="ALDOT Concrete Technician" />
<input id="Certification" name="Certification" type="hidden" value="ALDOT Concrete Technician" />


                </div>
                <div class="one columns ">

                        <label for="Score" class="hide-on-phones" style="white-space: nowrap">Score</label>
                        <span class="clearfix hide-on-phones"></span>
                        <label for="Score" class="show-on-phones">Score &nbsp; </label>
                        <span class="clearfix show-on-phones"></span>                        


<input disabled="disabled" id="Score" name="Score" type="text" value="70" />
<input id="Score" name="Score" type="hidden" value="70" />


                </div>
                <div class="two columns ">

                        <label for="ExamProficiency" class="hide-on-phones" style="white-space: nowrap">Proficiency</label>
                        <span class="clearfix hide-on-phones"></span>
                        <label for="ExamProficiency" class="show-on-phones">Proficiency &nbsp; </label>
                        <span class="clearfix show-on-phones"></span>                        


<input disabled="disabled" id="ExamProficiency" name="ExamProficiency" type="text" value="PASS" />
<input id="ExamProficiency" name="ExamProficiency" type="hidden" value="PASS" />


                </div>
                <div class="one columns ">

                        <label for="Approve" class="hide-on-phones" style="white-space: nowrap">Approve</label>
                        <span class="clearfix hide-on-phones"></span>
                        <label for="Approve" class="show-on-phones">Approve &nbsp; </label>
                        <span class="clearfix show-on-phones"></span>                        

                    <input GroupName="group_67" falsevalue="N" id="Approve" name="Approve" truevalue="Y" type="radio" value="False" />
                </div>
                <div class="one columns ">

                        <label for="Reject" class="hide-on-phones" style="white-space: nowrap">Reject</label>
                        <span class="clearfix hide-on-phones"></span>
                        <label for="Reject" class="show-on-phones">Reject &nbsp; </label>
                        <span class="clearfix show-on-phones"></span>                        

                    <input GroupName="group_67" falsevalue="Y" id="Reject" name="Reject" truevalue="N" type="radio" value="False" />
                </div>
       </div>
<input id="PersonCertificationId" name="PersonCertificationId" type="hidden" value="10089" /><input id="RefWtfMembersId" name="RefWtfMembersId" type="hidden" value="10006" /><input id="WorkerId" name="WorkerId" type="hidden" value="10556" /><input id="WtfApprovalId" name="WtfApprovalId" type="hidden" value="0" /><input id="MembersId" name="MembersId" type="hidden" value="10011" /><input id="PreviousUrl" name="PreviousUrl" type="hidden" value="" /><input id="LastModifiedById" name="LastModifiedById" type="hidden" value="" />
    </span>
    <div class="DetailLine NewRow Required" id="RequiredFieldLegend">
        *Indicates a required field
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="sixteen columns">
                <input name="command" type="submit" value="Save" class="small nice blue radius button"  />
                <input name="command" type="submit" value="Cancel" class="small nice white radius button"  />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    if ($('.required').not('#RequiredFieldLegend').length == 0) {
        $('#RequiredFieldLegend').hide();
    }
</script>


                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="footerContainer" class="row">
            <div >
                <div id="footerLinksContainer" class="radius-top">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                                <img src="/camms/Content/themes/camms/Images/icons/ico_book.png" alt="" class="icon" />

                                    <span class="disabled">Construction Manual</span>

                        </li>
                        <li>
                                <img src="/camms/Content/themes/camms/Images/icons/ico_manual.png" alt="icon" class="icon" />

                                    <span class="disabled">Spec Book</span>

                        </li>
                        <li>
                                <img src="/camms/Content/themes/camms/Images/icons/ico_test.png" alt="icon" class="icon" />

                                    <span class="disabled">Testing Manual</span>

                        </li>
                        <li>
                                <img src="/camms/Content/themes/camms/Images/icons/ico_search.png" alt="icon" class="icon" />




                            <a href="/camms/CertificationApproval/Search/Certifications/Approvals/">Search</a>


                        </li>
                        <li>
                                <img src="/camms/Content/themes/camms/Images/icons/ico_helpBook.png" alt="icon" class="icon" />

                                    <span class="disabled">Help</span>

                        </li>
                        <li>
                                <img src="/camms/Content/themes/camms/Images/icons/ico_help.png" alt="icon" class="icon" />

                                    <span class="disabled">Help Desk</span>

                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>










</body>

</html>
```

This is the Edit ViewModel:

```
    using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using Camms.ValueObjects;
using CammsWeb.Code;
using CammsWeb.Code.Attributes;
using CammsWeb.Attributes;
using CammsWeb.Code.TemplateElements;

namespace CammsWeb.Models.Categories.Certifications.Approvals
{
    public class ApprovalEditViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        public long PersonCertificationId { get; set; }

        public long RefWtfMembersId { get; set; }

        public long WorkerId { get; set; }

        public long WtfApprovalId { get; set; }

        public string MembersId { get; set; }

        // this will be Y or N for approve/reject
        public string Vote { get; set; }

        [Layout(3), DisplayName("Attendee"), Disable()]
        public string PersonName { get; set; }

        [Layout(4), DisplayName("Certification"), Disable()]
        public string Certification { get; set; }

        [Layout(1), DisplayName("Score"), Disable()]
        public double Score { get; set; }

        [Layout(2), DisplayName("Proficiency"), Disable()]
        public string ExamProficiency { get; set; }

        [Layout(1), DisplayName("Approve"), RadioButton(FalseValue = "N", TrueValue = "Y")]
        public string Approve { get; set; }

        [Layout(1), DisplayName("Reject"), RadioButton(FalseValue = "Y", TrueValue = "N")]
        public string Reject { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the question.  What do you mean each group is mutually exclusive?  Meaning if you pick an option in one group, all other groups must be unset?  Or do you mean only one option can be set within each group of radio buttons?  If 2 or more radio buttons share the same `name` attribute, they are by default mutually exclusive with each other.  So I'm not sure what you're trying to sovle with javascript.

Comment: I am trying to make it so that only one option in each group is mutually exclusive.  I can't make their names the same due to how the framework of this project works.  I wasn't here during the beginning of development and am having to code around a lot of things.

Comment: So how are you identifying them as groups in your code?  Are they wrapped in a particular element with a particular class, and that's how you know the groupings?  And once you know the grouping, does that grouping have a particular name that you need to use when the data is then posted back to the server?

Comment: The way this framework works, it reads from the metadata to generate the html.  The markup looks like this <input type="radio" name="Approve" id="Approve" groupname="group_1" /> <input type="radio" name="Reject" id="Reject" groupname="group_1" /> <input type="radio" name="Approve" id="Approve" groupname="group_2" /> <input type="radio" name="Reject" id="Reject" groupname="group_2" /> etc...

Comment: Why can't it, instead of setting a groupname attribute, also set the name?  That doesn't seem right.  But at any rate, I'll submit an answer now with how you can do it.

Comment: I just tried to do that and it won't set the name property to the same as the groupname...something in the framework must over write it.

Comment: I'd really look at the framework and see if it's set up properly and see if there's a different way to create a radio button list.  The answer I gave is a bit of a hack considering you have to use JS to fix what shouldn't need to be fixed from an HTML standpoint.  For example, pass in all the text/value options (e.g. like a dropdownlist, ala `SelectListItems` or something) and have that generate a full LIST of radio buttons -- not individual radio buttons.  But if it's truly not possible, then this is a last resort effort.

Comment: How are you trying to set the name property of the radio button?  Might be able to help there as well if you provide some sample code.  That might be a better place to start!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23650/discussion-between-eli-gassert-and-nathan)

Comment: Your model is for a single record.  Your view contains multiple records.  Either your model is a List of that VM class, or you're missing a class here.  In either case, your markup doesn't properly reflect the model.  Forget the Approve and Reject parts.  Comment out the `Disabled` Attribute for `PersonName` so that it's editable.  Then post back and tell me that it properly fills in the updated names for all the records in question when you do a post back.  It won't.  It can't!  But it'll serve as to why the radio button issue has little to do with the groupname.

Comment: Hi Eli, the what is returned is a List<ApprovalEditViewModel> so you are correct.  Everything else works fine, the only problem is with the radio buttons.  This project is not a "typical" MVC application so the way it works is a lot different and it's hard to find where the code is that does certain things.  If I could just loop through all the radio buttons on the page and make each group mutually exclusive it will work fine.  If I make the name property anything other than the property name from the viewmodel the data isn't mapped.

Comment: Nathan, I understand what you're saying, but you're not listening to what I'm saying.  Until you try the experiment I laid out above I cannot help you anymore.  The fact is, the naming convention you have does NOT follow standard List<Model> naming conventions.  Normally each field in a sequence would be named something like `[0].PersonName`, `[1].PersonName` or something along those lines.  See this article: http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx

Comment: The fact that none of your names work like that is your real problem.  Do whatever magic you want to make them "mutually exclusive" when you post back, the names will mash up and will not know how to bind back into a list.

Comment: Hi Eli, yes I know the way this thing was written is horrible and did not follow how mvc is supposed to be written nor does it truly follow MVVM but we are stuck having to code around all this nonsense.  Believe me when I say I've tried all kinds of things and any examples on the internet do not work in this project.  Would you tell me how I can loop all the radio buttons and compare their groupname attributes and I can make them mutually exclusive by doing this?

Comment: I'm sorry I can't.  You're not hearing me.  It has nothing to do with what I think looks good and is right from MVC/MVVM/whatever standards.  Your unwillingness to even try what I'm saying so I can show you precisely why it will not, under any circumstance, work makes it impossible for me to help.  If you want a hack, change to checkboxes instead of radio and use the first version of jsfiddle I showed you that uses the groupname to uncheck the others.  Best of luck with the project.

Comment: I don't understand what you are wanting me to do...I am new to the whole MVC style and this project doesn't follow any of the MVC tutorials or examples.  We have to "hack" everything in here because of how it was designed.  If I change the name property using the jsfiddle trick, the value isn't mapped to the property in the view model:  [Layout(1), DisplayName("Approve"), RadioButton(FalseValue = "N", TrueValue = "Y")]
        public string Approve { get; set; } does not have a value when I use the jsfiddle example to set the name's the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the `groupname` attribute, you can do this:

```
$(':radio[groupname]').change(function()
{
  var groupname = $(this).attr('groupname');
  var filter = ':radio[groupname="' + groupname + '"]';


  $(filter).attr('checked', false); // find all elements with the same groupname, uncheck them

  $(this).attr('checked', true); // reset to checked since we probably just unchecked it with the line above!
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7nAsJ/

Now, for this to work, names MUST be unique.  In the JSFiddle above, you'll see I renamed `Approve` and `Reject` to `Approve2` and `Reject2` in the sample HTML code.  So if you have two radio buttons with the name `Approve` then they're auto-grouped by HTML DOM standards and they will be automatically mutually exclusive.  If you can't have that, then there are two other options:

1. On load,change the name and IDs to append the group name.  Then use the JS above.  But if you're going to change the names anyway, then I suggest option #2...
2. Change the name to the groupname, and then no JS will be required anyway!  It's automatic.

To demonstrate, here's the code to fix the names: http://jsfiddle.net/7nAsJ/1/

```
$(':radio[groupname]').each(function()
{
  var groupname = $(this).attr('groupname');
  $(this).attr('name', groupname);
  $(this).attr('id', $(this).attr('id') + '_' + groupname); // set new ID to old ID_groupname for uniqueness
});
```

Comment: Hi Eli, thank you very much.  I used option #2 and it's working perfectly so far...at least on the front end.  If my data is passed back and mapped properly this is perfect!

Comment: Given the structure of your original data, even if we didn't use trickery to make it mutually exclusive, I don't really know how it'd work properly, to be honest.  The groupname isn't passed back.  It's just the name (which we've changed) and the value.  So trickery or not, if you passed back a name 'Approved' and value '1' or 'true' then how would your controller/action handler know if that was for group1 or group2?  But now we're back to the root of my questions in the comments on your original post, so no need to get back into that :)

Comment: Ouch, changing the name breaks how the data is mapped to the property in the viewmodel...I'm going to have to try another approach.  Do you know how I could loop all the radio buttons on the page and make them mutually exclusive based on their dynamic groupname attribute?

Comment: I moved this thread to a discussion so we can discuss the fundamental issues with the approach: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23650/discussion-between-eli-gassert-and-nathan

Comment: Hi Eli, our corporate firewall and/or proxy servers blocked the link you established.

Comment: After you paste HTML highlight it all and hit ctrl+k or click the code format icon (101010) in the toolbar.

Comment: It's like I need to loop all the radio buttons and make them mutually exclusive if their groupname attribute has the same value.

Answer (score 1):

> The way this framework works, it reads from the metadata to generate
>   the html. The markup looks like this `<input type="radio"
>   name="Approve" id="Approve" groupname="group_1" /> <input type="radio"
>   name="Reject" id="Reject" groupname="group_1" />`

Seeing you have an attribute called `groupname`, according to your comment, you should be able to do something similar to this:

```
$("input:radio").on("click", function(){
    var $currentInput = $(this);
    var groupName = $currentInput.attr("groupname");

    $("[groupname='" + groupName + "']").not($currentInput).prop("checked", false);
})
```

---

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/2PSEF/) - Manually clearing radio buttons in same group

---

Assuming all inputs have a groupname attribute, similar ot this:

```
<span>Group 1</span>
<input type="radio" groupname="group1"/>
<input type="radio" groupname="group1"/>
<input type="radio" groupname="group1"/>
<input type="radio" groupname="group1"/>
<br />
<span>Group 2</span>
<input type="radio" groupname="group2"/>
<input type="radio" groupname="group2"/>
<input type="radio" groupname="group2"/>
<input type="radio" groupname="group2"/>
```

Comment: I can't set the name property, just tried to force it but the way this custom framework was written the name is assigned to the control based on the property name in the view model.

Comment: @Nathan: I updated the answer to use the new information to have provided regarding the already existing `groupname` attribute.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response and your demo works great, however in this project it removes a portion of the pages content.  I have no idea why but part of the page isn't showing up now.  When I comment out the jquery it's back to normal.  I have no idea why something that is only looking at an input type radio would affect the entire page.  This is a strange one...

Comment: @Nathan: I only used a selector that matched the radio buttons for the demo as I don't know your full HTML layout. Off course, if you have a `div` or any closer element which allows you to better target the exact input controls you should be using that as part of your selector. Hope you get it to work in the end :)